# Using JavaScript to change CSS properties of SVG circles for all circles that was not clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I now contain a list that contains several `li` and each `li` contain a `circle` I would like a way to efficiently and not hardcode a way to change the class of each circle that was not clicked to `disabled` and for the circle that was clicked to `active`.

How can I efficiently, by looping and not hard coding programatically do this using JS?

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <svg>
         <circle ...> </circle>
         <span> Text </span>
     </svg>

   </li>
    --> repeated several more times
</ul>
```

If I click on a circle, how do I efficiently change the class of the circle being clicked to `active` and all of the circle not clicked to `disabled` and also the `span` inside the `svg` to be visible or not?

Comment: do you use plain JS or some libary like jQuery?

Comment: You have a span element inside the svg element. You can't do it, Inside an svg element you have to use the `text` element for text

Comment: @MRonline I can add libraries if required like jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't need to set 'disabled' (as in sippet below).

```
let circles = [...document.querySelectorAll('circle')];

circles.forEach(c => c.onclick = e=> {
  circles.forEach(cc=> cc.classList.remove('active'));
  e.target.classList.add('active');
});
```

```js
let circles = [...document.querySelectorAll('circle')];

circles.forEach(c => c.onclick = e=> {
  circles.forEach(cc=> cc.classList.remove('active'));
  e.target.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
svg { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
.circ {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active { fill: red; }
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
     <svg>
         <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circ active"  />       
         <span> Text </span>
     </svg>
   </li>
   
   <li>
     <svg>
         <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circ"  />       
         <span> Text </span>
     </svg>
   </li>
   
   <li>
     <svg>
         <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circ"  />       
         <span> Text </span>
     </svg>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How could this be modified to add disabled to the class if it was not clicked?

Comment: I suppose this works.

-> let circles = [...document.querySelectorAll('circle')];

circles.forEach(c => c.onclick = e => {
    circles.forEach(function(circle){
        circle.classList.remove('active');
        circle.classList.add('disabled');
    });
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    e.target.classList.remove('disabled');
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text` to have texts in an SVG. Try the below code.

```js
let circles = document.querySelectorAll('g');

circles.forEach(g => {
  let text = g.querySelector('text');
  text.classList.add('hide');
  let circle = g.querySelector('circle');
  circle.classList.add('disabled');
  circle.onclick = function(e) {
    this.classList.remove('disabled');
    this.classList.add('active');
    text.classList.remove('hide');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  fill: green;
}

.disabled {
  fill: grey;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
     <g>
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      <text x="25" y="100" fill="red">Circle 1</text>
     </g>
    </svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
     <g>
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      <text x="25" y="100" fill="red">Circle 2</text>
     </g>
    </svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting, but I have one <li> for each svg, would this still work? I've taken the code above since its easier to understand imo, however it does lack the text component.

Comment: yes, since we use `querySelectorAll`, the number of `li`'s does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Jquery

First give to each circle id like that

```
     <li>
         <svg>
             <circle id="Circle1"> </circle>
            <span> Text </span>
         </svg>

     </li>
    <li>
        <svg>
            <circle id="Circle2"> </circle>
            <span> Text </span>
        </svg>

    </li>
    <li>
        <svg>
            <circle id="Circle3"> </circle>
            <span> Text </span>
        </svg>

    </li>
```

On Clicking any add class Active

```
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        $("#Circle"+i).click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    }
```

Function to check if class is found and add disabled class if not

```
   function Check(){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
          if(!$("#Circle"+i).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).addClass("disabled");
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with plain Javascript (like the other answers before), or you may use jQuery. In my opinion easier to toggle classes.

```
$("svg").on("click", function () {
        // reset all svg classes:
        $("svg").addClass("disabled").removeClass("active");
        // set for the clicked svg:
        $(this).removeClass("disabled").addClass("active");
    });
```

see: [jQuery .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) [jQuery .addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-className)